# Cannot install symfony eclipse plugin

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony

I am getting this error message whilst trying to install the symfony2 plugin on eclipse:

cannot find : http://p2.dubture.com it seems to not access the symfony repository.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the [plugin website](http://symfony.dubture.com/installation/), it shows that the url you need to use to install the plugin is:

http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/

Also, ensure that you remove any old entries from the Add Software wizard.